# Multiple turtlebot 3 simulation in ROS2

Tags: ros2, simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to simulate multiple turtlebot3 in ROS2 dashing to no avail.
If anyone knows how to do this that could answer my question I'd be really grateful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355006/multiple-turtlebot-3-simulation-in-ros2/) by [JulioEsteban](https://answers.ros.org/users/55813/julioesteban/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been working on this also, but It's quite cumbersome.

As far as I know, the tb3 models are spawned as `.sdf` models directly on the [turtlebot3_gazebo](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations) world files () whereas the `tf` is created by a robot publisher that uses a urdf  on the [trutlebot_description](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_description)

What I've done is the following:

- Create copies of the [tb3 models](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/tree/ros2/turtlebot3_gazebo/models) with a different name (I.e tb_1_burger, tb_2_buger)
- Edit the [model.sdf](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/blob/ros2/turtlebot3_gazebo/models/turtlebot3_burger/model.sdf) files on the new copies by adding the namespace tags according.
- Edit the [world file](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/blob/ros2/turtlebot3_gazebo/worlds/empty_worlds/burger.model) that you are launching to add the new models.

At this point you will have the two robots on gazebo, but the `tf` tree will be duplicated, so now it's time to edit the `.urdf`.  For this it's possible to create a `.xacro` file, but depending on which ros2 version you are using that can change quite a lot.  So a long and boring way to do this is to

- Create copies of the `.urdf` files for the new robots/models. You can find them in the [turtlebot_description/urdf](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/tree/ros2/turtlebot3_description/urdf) and there you need to manually change the links, joints to include the prefix.
- Finally, you need to update the [robot_state_publisher.launch](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/blob/ros2/turtlebot3_gazebo/launch/robot_state_publisher.launch.py) to launch the different `.urdf` files you just created.

At this point, the multiple tb3 models should work, but it may still be some issues I haven't detected yet.

Hope this helps!

Mario

---

Originally posted by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) with karma: 802 on 2020-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [quadcopter](https://answers.ros.org/users/71168/quadcopter/) on 2021-03-01**:
Hi I was trying to follow your instructions but I kind of confused what to exactly edit. Like in the part where we have to add the namespaces what do we exactly have to fill it in with?

**Comment by [Neubist](https://answers.ros.org/users/71431/neubist/) on 2021-03-04**:
Are you able to provide an example for changing the links in the urdf files, along with how to update the robot_state_publisher.launch file?  Thanks so much!